# Number of possible unions of a countable number of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

If $\{ A_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a countable sequence of distinct sets, then is the number of possible distinct unions between any two or more of the sets in the sequence uncountable? I would like a proof.

By possible distinct unions I mean unions such as $A_{1} \cup A_{2}$, $A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3}$, $A_{2} \cup A_{3}$, etc.

**Background**
I am doing self study on measure theory, and am trying to prove that a $\sigma$-algebra that contains a countable number of distinct sets is uncountable.

Comment: Can you think of a way to get a function from the described set to a subset of the power set of the positive integers?

Comment: Do you mean *finite* unions? or arbitrary unions.

Comment: @SolidSnake I mean arbitrary unions, since I want to apply this result to a $\sigma$-algebra with a countable number of distinct sets

Comment: So, in that case, consider abiessu's comment: assign each union a subset of the set of positive integers in the following way: Each union corresponds to the set of indexes of the $A_i's$ involved in the union, for example, $A_1\cup A_2$ would be assigned to $\{1,2\}$. It's easier to count the number of subsets of the positive integers set (however, keep in mind that not all the unions are necessary different, here, you need to impose more conditions on the sets $A_i$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to another answer, but to further address your main question: If you have countably infinite number of DISJOINT sets in your $\sigma$-algebra, then you can map every possible union to a subset of natural numbers simply by enumerating your disjoint sets as $A_1,A_2,A_3, \ldots$ and then for a given union, just form the set of indices $i$ of sets $A_i$ that are included in the union. It is a well known fact that the power set of natural numbers, i.e. the set of all subsets of natural numbers, is uncountable, and one way to see it is by the famous so-called diagonalization argument, where you suppose there are countably many natural number subsets, call them $X_i$ and then you construct a new subset $Y$ where $i \in Y$ if and only if $i \notin X_i$. Then $Y$ is not any of your enumerated subsets $X_i$.

Comment: For my purposes this answer works great, as I know every infinite $\sigma$-algebra contains an infinite sequence of disjoint events. Thus the argument you presented can be used from here to prove that every infinite $\sigma$-algebra is uncountable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be uncountable, let ${A_n}=\{n\}$, so the sets are $\{1\},\{2\},\{3\}\dots$

Then it is clear that the sets that are the union of two or more of these sets are the subsets of $\mathbb N$ with at least two elements.

This subset is not countable, we can find a bijection with the set of infinite binary sequences with at least two ones (which is uncountable).

The bijection is as follows: Send a set $A$ to the sequence where term $i$ is one if $i\in A$ and the term $i$ is zero if $i\not\in A$

---

The reason why the set of binary sequences with at least two ones is countable is that the set of binary sequences with $1$ one or no ones is countable.

---

Added: The set can also be countable. Consider the following sets: $\mathbb N-\{1\},\mathbb N-\{2\},\mathbb N-\{3\},\mathbb N-\{4\}\dots$

The union of at least two sets must be $\mathbb N$. So the set of possible unions has exactly $1$ element and is countable.

Comment: Keep in mind that all the unions don't need to be different, for example, if $A_i:= \{1,...,i\}$, then every union equals $\{1,...,j\}$ where $j$ is the greater index on the union.